# Javascript: eval() function does not work for value with double digits

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple calculator; however, my eval() function does not work for numbers with more than single digits. For example, 20 * 30. This maybe a simple fix, but I am not too sure how to go about this. I have tested the eval function with a different program but for some reason it doesn't work with mines. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Calculator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="center">
<div id="calc">
 
<form name="my_calculator">
 <input type="text" name="answ">
 <br>

  <input type="button" value=" C " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value = '' ">
  <input type="button" value=" 0 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 0 ' ">
  <input type="button" value=" = " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value =  eval(my_calculator.answ.value)">
  <input type="button" value=" / " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' / ' ">
 <br>
  <input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 1 ' ">
  <input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 2 ' "> 
  <input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 3 ' "> 
  <input type="button" value=" * " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' * ' ">
 <br>
  <input type="button" value=" 4 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 4 ' ">
  <input type="button" value=" 5 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 5 ' ">  
  <input type="button" value=" 6 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 6 ' "> 
  <input type="button" value=" - " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' - ' ">
 <br>

  <input type="button" value=" 7 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 7 ' ">
  <input type="button" value=" 8 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 8 ' ">  
  <input type="button" value=" 9 " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' 9 ' "> 
  <input type="button" value=" + " onclick="my_calculator.answ.value += ' + ' ">

  
 <br>

</form>


</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cause ` 1 2 ` is not a valid number cause of the whitespaces . Remove them and itll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One "quick fix" would be to remove white spaces within the eval function:

```
eval(my_calculator.answ.value.replace(/\s/g, ''))
```

Of course, another potential solution would be to remove excess spaces from the buttons themselves.

[See JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/rhk6zovL/).

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces around each of your characters.

`20` is twenty but `2  0` is two and zero next to each other.

Two numbers next to each other is a syntax error in JavaScript.